# How are these fake accounts being created?

Tags: discussion

We're currently having an issue with a troll on this site, who is creating accounts that impersonate (real) user Eddie Kal.

https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/51692/eddie-kal
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/51691/eddie-kal

My question is, aren't usernames meant to be unique? How is it possible for someone to be creating these?

Comment: I've seen users change their name in the past (one of our previously moderators did it a lot).  I think the unique identifier is in the user code (in the links above the number (51691/51692))  but that's a suspicion

Comment: I suspect this is the same idiot I refer to obliquely in this other thread ([Content filters and/or IP range blocking?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2313/content-filters-and-or-ip-range-blocking)) asking how better we could prevent this kind of abuse in general.  (NB: Not Eddie himself, but whoever it is that is trying to impersonate him.)

Answer (score 6):

If you've been flagging these posts, please continue to do so. Meanwhile I have escalated this case to the Community Management team and they should have higher level moderation and administration tools to help

Comment: I have been flagging these consistently. I'm concerned with how easy it is for display names to be spoofed. I was under the impression these should be considered unique per site (at least up to appearance). I thought they might be using Unicode lookalike characters, but I confirmed that they are not.

Comment: The names are allowed to be the same, the user IDs are the ones that are unique

Comment: I'm curious, is there any good reason to allow multiple users with the same display name?  I can't think of a compelling use case, and allowing this seems to open the door to exactly the kind of abuse mentioned in this thread.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi I agree that this type of abuse is somehow way too easy. I think one of the motivations for allowing non-unique display names is to enable everyone to use their real name (first name or full name) as display name, even if someone has the same name as you.

Comment: @Earthliŋ, thank you for that idea.  I can't say as I agree with that approach, precisely because of the excessive opportunity for abuse.  For something similar, that still allows for unique handles, SE could just stick a number on the end for successive iterations of the same handle -- much like is done for email accounts.

Comment: The spammer strikes again... https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/51714/eddie-kukelkal https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/51713/kukelcamel ...

Comment: Somebody's been creating new accounts (like 10-20 in the past hour) and spamming nonesense and slurs as new questions. Basically all the new questions are the same spammer.

Comment: We need a way of solving these issues. I'm actually a little surprised there's no efficient moderation technique across StackExchange for situations like this (e.g. an IP range ban).

Answer (score 2):

i cannot comment yet because i lack the website points but my question was a target of the abuse in the past days

fortunately things have slowed down but i too checked the new users list and it seems theres a lot of similarly named chinese accounts being created currently, please look into this

Comment: just as i posted this there is a new wave of accounts posting gore pictures

Comment: What is your connection with these spammers?

Comment: they posted abusive answers to my question

Comment: Huh? Nothing about the recent spate of spammers suggests they're Chinese.

Comment: thats not what i meant, if you take a look at the latest batch of new users there are a lot of chinese accounts that have a similar name containing the characters 平台总代 and identical about mes

Comment: Profile spammers are unfortunately a thing around the SE network. I have deleted the accounts.

Comment: @gashapon_gyambura Apologies, I thought you were referring to the previous spate of spammers (circa June 23)